# How to put mmap file into memory?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, mmap

I load a NumPy file into memory using mmap.

```py
a = np.load('something.npy', mmap = 'r')
```

But what do I do if I want to use a segment of it, for example a[10] in the real memory? Especially it will be useful for debugging purposes. Since I can't access it in the PyCharm debugger.

Comment: you could always put something like b = a[10] to the code and put there a break point. That way you can investigate what is in b or a, no ?

Comment: no, a[10] is a 2d array. and in scientific mode, it doesn't show as a table.

Comment: sorry I can't help with scientific mode. For detailed debugging you can use the spyder editor and mark code that you like to investigate